# $a_1 \in [0,\pi] ,a_{n+1} = sin(a_n)$ prove or disprove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$a_1 \in [0, \pi], a_{n+1} = sin(a_n)$$
Prove or disprove that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$$

I've managed to show that sequence is bounded and decreasing thus convergence is proven, however I fail to find a way to prove that the limit is 0... a hint would be very appreciated

Comment: Yes! thank you!

Comment: I am wondering if this can be proved by contraction mapping? For example, $$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|=|2\sin(\frac{x-y}2)\cos(\frac{x+y}2)|<|(x-y)\cos(\frac{x+y}2)|$$, how to find a universal constant $c$ and $0<c<1$, such that: $$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|<c|x-y|$$